LilyPond: stretch space between piano staves to make room for kneed beam
Consider the following LilyPond fragment:
\version "2.24.3"
\language "italiano"

global = {
    \key reb \major
    \time 9/8
}

cu = { \change Staff = "right" }
cd = { \change Staff = "left" }

right = \new Staff = "right" {
    \global
    \relative do' {
    <<
        {
            <fa lab>2.
            \(dob'4 reb8\)
        } \\
        {s2. lab4.}
    >>
        <fa lab>2. ^\(<lab dob>4 lab8\) |
    }
}

left = \new Staff = "left" {
    \global
    \relative do' {
        \clef bass
        \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn
        \once \override Beam.auto-knee-gap = #2
        <<
            {
                reb,,16 _(lab' reb fa \cu \stemDown lab reb)
                \cd \stemUp fa,, _(do' fa \cu \stemDown lab do fa)
                \cd \stemUp lab,,_(fab' lab \cu \stemDown dob fab lab)
                \cd
            } \\
            {
                reb,,,4. fa4. lab4.
            }
        >>
        <<
            {
                reb,16 _(lab' reb fa \cu \stemDown lab reb)
                \cd \stemUp fa,, _(do' fa \cu \stemDown lab do fa)
                \cd \stemUp lab,, _(fab' lab \cu \stemDown dob lab' fab )\cd
            } \\
            {
                \voiceTwo
                reb,,4. fa4. lab4.
            }
        >> |
    }
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff \with {
    }
    <<
        \accidentalStyle piano
        \right
        \left
    >>
    \layout {
        \context {
            \Score
            proportionalNotationDuration = #(ly:make-moment 1/16)
            \override SpacingSpanner.uniform-stretching = ##t
        }
    }
}

It produces the following engraving:

The only way I found to fix the ugliness of the kneed beams is to add
    \new PianoStaff \with {
        \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing =
            #'((basic-distance . 10))
    }
    <<
        ...

However, this globally changes the distance between all staves. I tried to override it locally with \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-staff-spacing.basic-distance, but it had no effect. I tried to increase stretchability in the hope that LilyPond would stretch the space to make room for the kneed beam, but it also had no effect.
Is there a way to stretch the space automatically or increase the space only inside these two bars?
Update
Here is the desired engraving. It would be nice to get it without changing the staff distance globally.


What do you mean by ‘kneed’?  (I'd assume that a ‘knee’ was a kink or bend in a beam, but all the beams there are straight.)

As a pianist, it looks completely readable to me... Can you clarify the issue that you see? Is it the slightly funny shape of the beam in the first part of the second measure? I didn't even notice it until I was trying to imagine what one might object to...

@gidds The "kneed beam" in LilyPond has notes going up and down. I don't know if it is a common term or specific to LilyPond.

@paulgarrett It's just not the worst case. Yes, the shape is funny, and the note heads are too close to the beam, not leaving space for other elements. LilyPond also warns that it "may not find good beam slope." If you increase the staff distance, the warnings disappear. I updated the question with a picture of the desired engraving.

The issue here is that the default space is not sufficient to nicely space in the left hand f with accidental and the right hand ab. You can see this if you remove the accidental: Then there is no issue with placing the beam. Note that spacing with regard to cross staff beams is very complicated, as the Beam placement would depend on the staff distance, but the staff distance would need to take beam positions into account. This means that when the final beam positions are calculated this might give rise to spacing issues.
Now, there are multiple ways to mend this. As far as I know Lilypond does not really have a user friendly way to add a local minimum spacing to a positions. But what we can to is to force the Beam to start on a lower position that the right hand ab by adding an invisible ab to the right hand:
<< <fa lab>2. \new Voice { \hideNotes fa, } >> ^\(<lab' dob>4 lab8\) |

One option would be to allow Lilypond to draw the Beam through the Accidental by doing something like:
reb,16 _(lab' reb \once\override Accidental.Y-extent = #'(-1.5 . 0.8) fa \cu \stemDown lab reb)

But then, if you really want to increase the spacing what you can do is to add a small spacer like this:
<>-\tweak Y-offset -7 -\tweak X-extent #'(+inf.0 . -inf.0) -\tweak Y-extent #'(+inf.0 . -inf.0) _" "

Here is a MWE with all of there options in context:
<<
  \new Staff = "up" {
    \time 3/8
    \sectionLabel "Default"
    s4.
  }
  \new Staff = "down" {
    \clef bass
    \voiceOne
    d,16 a, d fis \change Staff = "up" \voiceTwo a d'
  }
>>

<<
  \new Staff = "up" {
    \time 3/8
    \sectionLabel "Invisible note"
    << s4. \new Voice { \hideNotes a } >>
  }
  \new Staff = "down" {
    \clef bass
    \voiceOne
    d,16 a, d fis \change Staff = "up" \voiceTwo a d'
  }
>>

<<
  \new Staff = "up" {
    \time 3/8
    \sectionLabel "Beam through Accidental"
    s4.
  }
  \new Staff = "down" {
    \clef bass
    \voiceOne
    d,16 a, d \once\override Accidental.Y-extent = #'(-1.5 . 0.8) fis \change Staff = "up" \voiceTwo a d'
  }
>>

<<
  \new Staff = "up" {
    \time 3/8
    \sectionLabel "Spacer"
    <>-\tweak Y-offset -7 -\tweak X-extent #'(+inf.0 . -inf.0) -\tweak Y-extent #'(+inf.0 . -inf.0) _" "
    s4.
  }
  \new Staff = "down" {
    \clef bass
    \voiceOne
    d,16 a, d fis \change Staff = "up" \voiceTwo a d'
  }
>>



This is a great answer!  I'm wondering if there may not be one more option: to manually control the beam positions?

Manual positioning of the beam doesn't change the vertical space between staves.
